# inner product space and fixed vector

Tags: linear-algebra

My professor gave this question:

> $V$ is an inner product space, $v$ and $w$ are fixed vectors in $V$. Let $T:V\to V$ be a linear map such that $T(u)=(u,v)w$. Find $T^*$.

Now I need to find the rank of $T$ and to find the matrix that represents $T$ by the standard basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$? So I found $T^*$ and according to my calculation it is $T^*(x)=\overline{(w,x)}v$.

Now assuming I am not wrong with $T^*$, how can I find rank$(T)$? I know that $$\text{rank}(T)=\text{rank}(TT^*)=\text{rank}(T*T)$$ but does this help me?

I do not know what $v$ and $w$ are and without that how can I  calculate what $T$ is doing the vectors of the basis in order to see how the matrix would look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: $(u, v)$ is always a scalar. You should be able to conclude on $Rank(T)$ from that, assuming that neither $v$ nor $w$ is the zero vector.

Comment: is my T* is true ?

Comment: Seems correct to me.

Comment: The way I see it is that assuming w and v are not the zero vector then we know that each time we look at T(u) while is also different from zero we get cw (while c must be different then zero because v is not zero and so as u). Therefore we will always get a vector that is different then zero meaning the rank(T) = dim (V). right ?

Comment: rank should always be $1$ assuming that neither $v$ nor $w$ is zero, because you can only map elements to a linear combination of one vector.

Comment: ohhh ok so I am understand that dimImT=sp{w}. that is really make sense. but what would happen if if v is the zero vector you can not conclude from it that (u,v)=0. am I wrong ?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8800/discussion-between-wanttolearn-and-narut-sereewattanawoot)